# changing the image of a draw2d button after creation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, draw2d

I am writing an eclipse plugin using draw2d. I am creating a draw2d button using the constructor : Button(Image image). At some point I want to change the image on that button! I can not find a way of doing it. Can anyone help me please?

Kind Regards,
Kyriakos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
Button button = ...
Image newImage = ...

((Label) button.getChildren().get(0)).setIcon(newImage);
```

It's certainly not nice, but it seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. The function that sets the image on the button is `Clickable.setContents`, which is `protected`. There is nothing in the documentation telling why this was done... You can try to inherit from `Button` and adding a new function to implement this.

Comment: That's what I did. Thank you!